# Problems using SoapUI plugin in Junit tests

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit, soapui

I'm having a lot of problems with **SoapUI** tests in my Java project.

Objective: run the SoapUI tests in the unity tests phase (before building on Heroku). The integration must be thourgh **Gradle**.

What did I do?: I Followed the instructions of the most used SoapUI gradle plugin repository:
https://github.com/byte-shifter-ltd/soapui-gradle-plugin

I needed to change some things and here is my code:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    soapUIVersion = '5.3.1-RC'
    springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE' 
}
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    maven { url 'http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/' }
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath('gradle.plugin.io.byteshifter:soapui-gradle-plugin:5.3.1-RC')
  }
}

apply plugin: io.byteshifter.plugins.soapui.SoapUIPlugin
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

def repositoryPath = 'lib'

repositories {
  maven { url 'http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/' }

  mavenCentral()

  flatDir {
    dirs "/home/iadtec/git"
  }
}

bootRun {
  [...]
}

dependencies {

[...]

  testCompile("com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:$soapUIVersion")
}
```

Build gradle (Gradle > refresh grade project) works properly, but when I tried to run the tests by using the right click button in the test class and "Run as" > "JUnit test" I get the following error:

```
18:32:22,702 INFO  [PluginManager] Adding plugin from [C:\Users\filip\.soapuios\plugins\ready-mqtt-plugin-dist.jar]
18:32:22,702 INFO  [PluginManager] Adding plugin from [C:\Users\filip\.soapuios\plugins\soapui-swagger-plugin-2.2-dist.jar]
18:32:22,772 ERROR [PluginManager] Failed to load module [ready-mqtt-plugin-dist.jar]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fife/ui/rtextarea/RTextArea
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.<clinit>(UISupport.java:148)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:139)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:420)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:382)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
18:32:22,772 ERROR [PluginManager] Failed to load module [soapui-swagger-plugin-2.2-dist.jar]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:139)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:420)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
18:32:22,773 INFO  [PluginManager] Adding plugin from [C:\Users\filip\.soapuios\plugins\ready-uxm-plugin-1.0.1-dist.jar]
18:32:22,774 INFO  [PluginManager] Adding plugin from [C:\Users\filip\.soapuios\plugins\readyapi-postman-1.0.1.jar]
18:32:22,774 ERROR [PluginManager] Failed to load module [readyapi-postman-1.0.1.jar]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:139)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:420)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
18:32:22,774 ERROR [PluginManager] Failed to load module [ready-uxm-plugin-1.0.1-dist.jar]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:139)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:420)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:382)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
18:32:22,775 INFO  [PluginManager] Adding plugin from [C:\Users\filip\.soapuios\plugins\readyapi-swaggerhub-plugin-1.0.jar]
18:32:22,776 ERROR [PluginManager] Failed to load module [readyapi-swaggerhub-plugin-1.0.jar]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:139)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:420)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:382)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
18:32:22,777 INFO  [PluginManager] 5 plugins loaded in 76 ms
18:32:22,777 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
18:32:23,165 WARN  [Tools] Could not delete temporary directory C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Temp\51718f7e-b270-4c3c-818c-ce58a6f4f306
```

Please, can anyone save me (help me)???

What should I do???